# Reflection of light from a plane surface

Tags: optics, reflection

Why do we witness scattering of light from mobile screen even when we have a plane screen to reflect light falling from any source of light (tubelight) onto the screen?

Comment: I think we need some clarification.  By "mobile screen" do you mean the screen of a mobile phone, or just a moving mirror?  And I don't understand what you mean to say with "a plane screen to reflect light falling from any source of light (tubelight) onto the screen",   By "tubelight" do you mean a beam of light having a limited cross section?

Comment: Yes I did mean the screen of our mobile phone and the tubelight refers to as a beam of a light

Comment: I"m afraid I still don't understand your setup.  What is the plane screen that is reflecting light onto the screen?

Comment: Usually light gets scattered when it passes through a different medium and when it comes out of the medium from the other side then it bends due to difference in wavelength , this phenomenon is seen in prism , light enters from one side and comes out from the other , because the other side is not parallel to the side from where it entered hence it splits white light , and the same reason why glass slabs do not show such scattering of light . My doubt is that yesterday while placing my phone onto the table I saw a band of 7 colour that were formed on to the screen beside the reflection of

Comment: Tubelight , and I am confused that the light beam that came from tubelight fall on the surface of the phone and then reflected back to my eyes , but the medium it travelled was first light then the glass of the screen and then it entered the glass gets refracted and then reflected and then comes out from the same surface of the phone and comes to my eyes which is again the same screen and hence parallel to the first screen , then how could and corresponding to what do we see the band of 7 colour on the screen of the phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure without seeing the phenomenon, but believe that the colors that you are seeing do not originate in the glass window of your mobile phone.  I think that they are caused by diffraction from the structures under the glass: the pixels of the display.

I will comment that dispersion of white light into colors does occur in a parallel slab.  It is difficult to detect because all of the colors exit parallel to each other, but offset by a tiny amount.  To the eye it probably appears that no dispersion is taking place.

Comment: Thank you sir 